# From when format specifier '%g' for double starts printing in exponential format

Tags: c, printf

I would like to understand from when format specifier `%g` for double starts printing values in exponential format.

myTest.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  double val = 384615.38462;
  double val2 = 9999999;
  printf ("val = %g\n",val);
  printf ("val2 = %g\n",val2);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled using gcc :

```
gcc version 4.5.2 (GCC)
Target: i386-pc-solaris2.11
```

Output :

```
val = 384615
val2 = 1e+07
```

Question:
Why `val` is printed as integer and why `val2` has been converted to exponential format even when I have not used `%lf` in `printf`.

Is there a range from when it will start print values using exponential format? If yes, Is there any way we can guess what could be the value range ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [Not a dupe, but answers the question.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35476709/694733)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the `man 3 printf`:

> g, G
>
> The  double argument is converted in style f or e (or F or E for G conversions).  The precision specifies the number of significant digits.  If the precision is missing, 6 digits are given; if the precision is zero, it is treated as 1. **Style e is used if the exponent from its conversion is less than -4 or greater than or equal to the precision.** Trailing zeros are removed from the fractional part of the result; a decimal point appears only if it is followed by at least one digit.

And the C11 – ISO/IEC 9899:2011 standard draft N1570 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> g,G
>
> A double argument representing a floating-point number is converted in
>   style f or e (or in style F or E in the case of a G conversion specifier),
>   depending on the value converted and the precision. Let P equal the
>   precision if nonzero, 6 if the precision is omitted, or 1 if the precision is zero.
>   Then, if a conversion with style E would have an exponent of X:
>
> **— if P > X ≥ −4, the conversion is with style f (or F) and precision
>   P − (X + 1).**
>
> — otherwise, the conversion is with style e (or E) and precision P − 1.
>
> Finally, unless the # flag is used, any trailing zeros are removed from the
>   fractional portion of the result and the decimal-point character is removed if
>   there is no fractional portion remaining.
>   A double argument representing an infinity or NaN is converted in the style
>   of an f or F conversion specifier.

Answer (score 2):

The [man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) says

> **g, G**
>
> The double argument is converted in style f or e (or F or E for G conversions). The precision specifies the number of significant digits. If the precision is missing, 6 digits are given; if the precision is zero, it is treated as 1. ***Style e is used if the exponent from its conversion is less than -4 or greater than or equal to the precision.*** Trailing zeros are removed from the fractional part of the result; a decimal point appears only if it is followed by at least one digit.

Comment: So, DV: could you give me hits...?